# Question on linear independence of quotient space

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let $V$($F$) be a vector space of dimension $n$. Let $W$ is a subspace of $V$.

Consider $S$ = {$x_1, x_2,..., x_k$} be a subset of $V$, consider
$S'$ = {$W+x_1, W+x_2..., W+x_k$} be a subset of $\frac{V}{W}$.

Then I need to show the following:

Given $S$ is linearly independent implies $S'$ is linearly independent, then dim$W$ $\leq$ $n$-$k$

I know by a result that $S'$ is linearly independent iff $S$ is linearly independent and $W$ $\cap$ $L$($S$) = {$0$}

From this how could I conclude the above statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is to use the so-called "[dimension formula](https://planetmath.org/dimensionformulaeforvectorspaces)":
$$
\dim(W) + \dim(L(S)) = \dim(W + L(S)) + \dim(W \cap L(S)).
$$
Since $W + L(S) \subset V$, this means that
$$
\dim(L(S)) \geq \dim(W) + \dim(L(S)) - n.
$$

Comment: It is W..How does that imply anything?

Comment: @Gitika That is true for the map from $V$ but  incorrect for $\phi$, which is a map on $S$.

Comment: S $\cap$ W..I think

Comment: @Gitika Right. Now how does *that* imply anything?

Comment: @Gitika That should have been the span of $S$ as the domain of $\phi$, per my latest edit.

Comment: So here kernel is L(S) $\cap$ W

Comment: I know dimension of span of S is k

Comment: @Gitika Well, before that, what can you conclude about the dimension of $L(S) \cap W$?

Comment: Okayy..so we get kernel of phi is {0}

Comment: Dimension of that is 0

Comment: @Gitika Right, and now the point is that if $\dim(W) > n-k$, then the intersection must be non-trivial

Comment: So?..I already knew that W$\cap$ L(S) is zero

Comment: What have you tried to imply by taking this map..All I can get from there is finding kernel

Comment: @Gitika You're right, I apparently wasn't reading very closely. I'll just write the full answer then.

Comment: See my latest edit